# Designing new database table schema, any industry standard for shortest column names for storage and processing efficiency?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I'm designing a database table schema, I know shortest column name makes sense since I'll be passing a lot of username, names, password fields, saving bandwidth efficiency and cache storage.

My question is, is there an industrial standard or commonly used single character field name / column names for database?

```
 e.g. first name = f
 last name = n
 username = u
 id = i
 date of birth = d
 password = p
```

you get the idea. Does anyone have a suggestion on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget about optimizing by shortening column names. Make your column names readable and descriptive, and follow a reasonable naming convention.